# Minify JavaScript code in a JSPX page (in a Spring MVC WebApp)

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jstl, minify

So, I have a jspx page which has JS code in it, and part of the code is generated dynamically, so I can't minify and paste the minified code.

E.g. Let's imagine I draw a chart with Google Chart API, and the I fill the data with a forEach JSTL tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'data');
        data.addRows(${fn:length(chartData)});
        <c:forEach items="${chartData}" var="entry" varStatus="status">
           data.setValue(${status.count-1},0,${entry.value});
        </c:forEach>      
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('google_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 620, height: 300});    
    }
</script>
```

My ideal solution would be for there to exist a tag e.g. `<something:minify><script type="text/javascript"> .... </script></something:minify>` which would do the job, but I'm interested in all possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) can be used to minify code on-the-fly.
It's loosly based on Google Closure but is a lot faster and succeeds in some cases where Closure doesn't.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but it runs on Node.js.

Comment: "It is developed on NodeJS, but it should work on any JavaScript platform supporting the CommonJS module system (and if your platform of choice doesn’t support CommonJS, you can easily implement it, or discard the exports.* lines from UglifyJS sources)."